# text highlighting visual assist x

Tags: visual-studio, visual-assist

I am looking for a way to disable the text of similar values being highlighted when you click/edit a variable, i.e. I click `enemyValue` and type something next to it and it automatically highlights all the text. I have searched and cannot find anything.

[image]

Comment: I upvoted your question so you'll have enough rep to post a picture.  Also, this sounds like an IDE question.  What editor are you using to write your C++?

Comment: @Gunther Fox, Visual Assist X is an extension for Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks, I just added a picture for clarity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uncheck "Automatically highlight references to symbol under cursor" on the `Advanced | Refactoring` page of the Visual Assist X Options dialog.

Pressing ESC temporarily removes the highlights.

Comment: Menu bar | VAssistX | Visual Assist X Options... | Advanced | Refactoring

Answer (score 1):

In your Visual Studio look for "VAssistX" menu tab it's just next with "View" then click "Visual Assist X Options" then expand if not yet expanded the "Advance" TreeView then select "Display" and uncheck the "Highlight find results".

Hope this will help.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not seem to change my problem. Thanks for your reply, though.

Comment: did you try disabling your VA? If you have other productivity tools like Resharper they are the ones making the highlight of same text after disabling the VA

Comment: disabling my VAX gets rid of the error, yes, but I do like the other benefits of VAX! It is just hard to read those highlighted blocks. To be truthful, they can go away if you hit the Esc key, but they just come back very quickly. I am only running VAX in my Visual Studio, no other productivity tools.

Comment: I'll get back to you once I figure it out. I'm using that tool too but for me there's no problem since my background color is white that's why it's not a problem to me.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps: http://www.wholetomato.com/products/features/color.asp

In particular be aware that "VAX Find Reference" colours are defined at Tools | Options | Environment | Fonts and Colors. Scroll to "VA X ..." in the list box labeled "Display items".

Also pressing Esc disables some of the colouring.